# Is it correct to convert the object to the string type before converting to the int type?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an event handler that works when a certain element is clicked. Is it correct to convert the object to the string type before converting to the int type?

This is my code:

```
private void selectLanguage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int language = Convert.ToInt32((sender as PictureBox).Tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If the Tag Element has integer values only then you can directly convert it to int.

Comment: I suggest you use the [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) to help if the `Tag` is not a valid `int`. In addition, I assume the posted code is simply an example since the posted code does not really do anything with the `Tags` `int` value.

Comment: Tag values has object type elements

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to do without a ToString() method

Comment: It will work at compile time - but at runtime your `Tag` property may be null or it may be a type other than int or string. Take @JohnG 's advice and use TryParse and add error handling for if the parse doesn't result in an int

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Comment: _"I want to know if it is possible to do without a ToString() method"_ .... The `Tag` is technically an `Object`, however you can "cast" it to a `string` without errors… . I have to ask… why is using the `ToString()` method undesirable?

Comment: `if (...Tag is int i) ...` If you assigned an int, then it should still be there?

Comment: @DCAggie you want to say that if i "cast" it to `int` without "casting" to `string` it will be errors?

Comment: @IslomMakhsudov I'm saying that there will be errors if you call `.ToString()` if `Tag` is `null` or if `Tag` is an object who's string representation isn't something `Convert.ToInt32` can't handle. Convert can also result in `0` being returned when input is null which may be misleading. Use null checking ( `Tag?.ToString()` ) and check the bool return of TryParse to avoid these pitfalls. I've put together a fiddle to demonstrate https://dotnetfiddle.net/62jukE

Answer (score -1):

no problem, You should to learn the ctrl-prop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).